# Tkinter Treeview get element calling function

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I am generating my own Tkinter.Treeview and calling a function if a tag gets clicked. Inside those function I want to get the element of the Treeview that was clicked. Or being more precise i want to get the values of the element. Therefore I have tried the following but do just get back the name of the element as a string not as an item object.

```
def element_clicked(event):
    item = event.widget.focus()
    value = item["values"]
```

If the item which was clicked have been generated the following way ...

```
ttk.Treeview(mainWindow).insert("", "end", iid, text="MyElement", values=["The value I want to pass to my function!!!"])
```

... I do get back **"MyElement"** and values can't be read out of a string

Any ideas how to get the item and its values calling the function element_clicked()?

Comment: Someday I'll understand the reason behind the lack of [mcve] on treeview questions.

Comment: I am very sure there is a simple solution for this thats why I do not write the complete code ... its unimportant how the Treeview looked like

Comment: Sure but why give that 'burden' to answerer? Besides it shouldn't be _complete_ code.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out how to do it. That's the code:

```
def element_clicked(event):
    item = tree.focus()
    print(tree.item(item, "values"))
```